# underscorejs: smarter list rendering with _each or an alternative

Tags: list, each, underscore.js-templating

I want to render templates using `underscorejs`.

This code

```
var _ = require('underscore');
var tpl = 'Hello <% _.each(names, function(name) { %><%= name %>, <% }); %>!';
var compiled = _.template(tpl);
var data = {
  names: ['Marissa','Bill','Larry','Steve']
};
var result = compiled(data);
```

produces:

```
=> "Hello Marissa, Bill, Larry, Steve, !"
```

Well, the result does not look smart.

I need to request if `name` is not the last item, then output ", ", so I can get to the result:

```
"Hello Marissa, Bill, Larry, Steve!"
```

If I can query if the name is the one before last one, I can get to:

```
"Hello Marissa, Bill, Larry and Steve!"
```

How can I get to this result?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it:

```
 Hello <% var n=names.length-1; _.each(names, function(name,i) { %><%= name %><% if(i<n) %>, <% }); %>!
```

results in

```
=> "Hello Marissa, Bill, Larry, Steve!"
```

and

```
Hello <% var n=names.length-2; _.each(names, function(name,i) { %><%= name %><% if(i<n) %>, <% if(i==n) %> and <% }); %>!
```

results in

```
=> "Hello Marissa, Bill, Larry and Steve!"
```